# How does a Distributed Denial Of Service Attack work

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service

Let's assume that a hacker has already infected an X number of PCs , each one of them is online. How will he actually perform this attack? Just send ping requests or use his very precious tool to do it(Having the risk of it being revealed) ?
I do not understand the actual way

Comment: Have a look at this talk from the 32C3 for some more advanced attacks: https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7523-ddos_mitigation_epic_fail_collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible way (UDP-Flood/Reflection/Amplification-Attack):

the attacker might use the zombies to invoke [amplification/reflection-attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Reflected_.2F_Spoofed_attack) like the ones performed some days ago [link1](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2014/01/multiple-gaming-platforms-hit-with-apparent-ddos-attacks/) /  [link2](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/hackers-spend-christmas-break-launching-large-scale-ntp-reflection-attacks); the attack was (probably) an [NTP reflection attack](https://cert.litnet.lt/en/docs/ntp-distributed-reflection-dos-attacks)

In other words:

- you have 20.000 bots
- you have a list of 100 vulnerable NTP-servers with an 100 mbit/s - uplink
- you are able to flood any target with (theoretical) 10 GB/s UDP - traffic
- the victim is attacked from the NTP-servers, who received spoofed requests from the bots

the same applies for DNS-amplification-attacks or any other UDP-based floods

picture taken from Secureworks-Blog [DNS Amplification Variation Used in Recent DDoS Attacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20140719150817/http://www.secureworks.com/resources/blog/research/dns-amplification-variation-used-in-recent-ddos-attacks-update/)

[image]

Comment: Nice answer , are the packets 'normal' or with some missing parts?

Comment: the packets are normal and legit, just with a spoofed sender-ip